# Convert MySQL time with milliseconds to javascript timestamp with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timestamp, milliseconds

I have timestamp from mysql like : "2016-08-03 11:11:41.04000" .
This timestamp is the result of a CONCAT('date', ' ', 'time') select.

I need to convert the timestamp with PHP to a numeric only timestamp, so that I can use the timestamp in javascript with the milliseconds precision preserved.

Other questions regarding this subject only cover dates without the MySQL milliseconds fragment, or simply suggest strtotime(''datestring) * 1000, wich loses the milliseconds precision.

The millisecond precision needs to be preserved so it can be used in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) object. The constructor can consume nearly any date/time format.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2016-08-03 11:11:41.04000');
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
// output: 1470215501
```

As stated in the comment below, using `getTimestamp` will lose the milliseconds portion, as a UNIX timestamp is based on seconds and cannot store fractions of a second. You can think of your own timestamp syntax if you need to. For example, output the date & time without any delimiters in between each digit:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2016-08-03 11:11:41.04000');
echo $datetime->format('YmdHisu');
// output: 20160803111141040000
```

On the other hand, **JavaScript is able to parse a datetime string including milliseconds** directly. So you can also pass the input directly to JS, without transforming it in PHP.

```
var datetime = new Date('2016-08-03 11:11:41.04000');
console.log(datetime.toJSON());
```

Comment: This loses the milliseconds precision.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

Print your concatstring in PHP when using it inside your JS.
You could use the JS Date object to set the correct time preserving milliseconds. Here's a reference to the Date object:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

In short

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Let PHP fill in those parameters (year, month, milliseconds etc) inside your JS

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple PHP code for convert date with milliseconds from PHP format to JS timestamp format with keep milliseconds.

Convert `2016-08-03 11:11:41.040` to `1470206501040`:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = '2016-08-03 11:11:41.040';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $date);
$ts_micro = (float) ($date->getTimestamp() . '.' . $date->format('u'));
$ts_mili = (float) ($ts_micro * 1000);
echo round($ts_mili); //result: 1470206501040
```

For test, you can reverse convert `1470206501040` to `2016-08-03T11:11:41.040Z` time with JS:

```js
var d = new Date(1470222701040);
var n = d.toISOString();
document.write(n); //result: 2016-08-03T11:11:41.040Z
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used both the suggestions of @feeela and @sietse85.

In PHP :

```
$datetime  = new \DateTime('2016-08-03 11:11:41.04000');
$timestamp = $datetime->format('YmdHisu'); // 2016080311114104000
```

In javascript :

```
/**
 * 2016080311114104000
 * @param string yyyymmddhhiissuuuuuu
 */
function dateFromCustomTimestamp(date) {
    date = date.toString();
    return new Date(
        date.substring(0,4),
        date.substring(4,6),
        date.substring(6,8),
        date.substring(8,10),
        date.substring(10,12),
        date.substring(12,14),
        date.substring(14,20)/100
    );
}
```

Not very nice, but if solves the problem to convert a numeric representation of a timestamp with milliseconds preserved from mysql => php => javascript .

Comment: Glad you got it solved, solution might not be the cheekiest but now it works you could also try to improve the code :)

Comment: Well, the method is readable and self explanatory, At the moment I don't see any improvements...